# Not able to inject spring service class when using spring boot and JAXRSServerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, cxf, jax-rs, spring-boot

I have a stand alone app running with Spring Boot.  It registers a CXF servlet for Soap endpoints at the root of the app (/).  I have also added CXF jaxrs programatically via

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    /**
     * register cxf SOAP web services with spring boot
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/*");                 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        // register cxf SOAP REST services with spring boot
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider()));     
        factory.setResourceClasses(ConfigureSoapResponseServiceImpl.class);
        factory.setAddress("/rest");
        factory.create();
    }
}
```

So far this works for registering all my jaxws and jaxrs services.  However I'm not able to inject a service class into a rest endpoint.  I assume this is because I'm setting it up programmatically with the JAXRSServerFactoryBean.

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/config")
public interface ConfigureSoapResponseService {


    @GET
    @Path("/")  
    public List<String> getAllOperations(@QueryParam("wsdlLocation") String wsdlLocation);


}

@Service
public class ConfigureSoapResponseServiceImpl implements ConfigureSoapResponseService {


    @Autowired
    public WsdlInspectionService wsdlInspectionService;


    @Override
    public List<String> getAllOperations(String wsdlLocation) {     
        return wsdlInspectionService.getWsdlOperations(wsdlLocation);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
}


@Component("wsdlInspectionService")
public class WsdlInspectionServiceImpl implements WsdlInspectionService {


    public List<String> getWsdlOperations(String wsdlLocation) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I tried using the @PostConstruct annotation in the above code and by adding

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

but neither have worked.

In my cxf-servlet.xml.  Since I'm using Spring Boot I don't have an applicationContext.xml.  The rest of my cxf-servlet.xml consists of:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"  
xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd 
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">


<jaxws:endpoint 
    xmlns:tns="https://someService/"
    id="someService"
    address="/someService" 
    serviceName="tns:someService"
    endpointName="tns:someService" 
    implementor="net.livetv.ws.SomeServicePortImpl">
</jaxws:endpoint>

// etc...
```

For completeness, here is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

My error is a NullPointerException on the this line of code:

```
return wsdlInspectionService.getWsdlOperations(wsdlLocation);
```

It isn't injecting my service.  How can I set this up to inject it properly?

Comment: And why should it inject? The JAX-RS classes know nothing about Spring nor the application context and just create a new bean instance instead of getting one from the context or using the context for auto wiring. Also your web.xml is useless as Spring Boot doesn't do anything with it so this also means your `cxf-servlet.xml` isn't doing anything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002089/spring-boot-with-tomcat-and-cxf-servlet?rq=1 for more info on integration the two.

Comment: I would like to be able to inject a service class into the resource class.  The cxf-servlet.xml is registering the jaxws endpoints.

Comment: No it isn't as it isn't being loaded as Spring Boot / Embedded tomcat ignores the web.xml... Both are useless in this setup.

Comment: It is because if I remove the web.xml I get an exception in the maven war plugin.  I'm not explicitly calling out the maven war plugin in the pom.xml.  However, I'm building stand alone war not a jar so that is probably what is going on there.

Comment: As a side note, I think this question can be disregarded... I think I've decided to split this into two different apps.  I need my CXF jaxws to be routed to /* so I can't direct anything to /rest or anything for that matter.  Starting CXF JaxRS via the Application main was a work around to get the CXF jaxrs registered.  However I think I want to use Spring MVC instead of CXF Rest services as I think it would be better for a web front end.  Thanks for you help and insight.